# Server Alias in IIS

Tags: apache, iis

I would like to create the equivalent of Apache Server Alias entries in IIS 7.5. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand Apache's Server Aliases correctly, then what you're looking for is a Virtual Directory.  In IIS manager, right-click a website or folder and select "Add Virtual Directory."  You can then add a directory to the website with a specific alias (which will form part of the Url) and physical path (which can be anywhere on disk, not necessarily under the root folder of the website).

**EDIT:** suspecting that I've confused Apache's "alias" and "server alias" functions: you may be looking for an IIS site's "Bindings", which allow multiple domain names to be mapped to specific web applications.