# Read files from shared folder in php

Tags: php, iis, shared-directory

I have two machines, Machine A and Machine B in LAN connection. I have shared a folder on Machine A.

On machine B , iis is installed and using below code I am trying to access this shared folder but printing "Access Denied".

I am able to access this folder physically from machine B but can not access it from PHP code. Also , "ISR" and "IIS User" have access to this folder.

```
<?php

$dir = "\\\\X.X.X.X\\FileStorage";
if (is_dir($dir)) 
{
    if ($dh = opendir($dir))        
        print "Got Access";       
}
else {   print "Access Denied";}
```

?>

Comment: In Apache I would expect to have to create an Alias so that Apache knew it was allowed to access that folder. I would check that the equivalent in IIS has been done to allow that web server access to that share

Comment: This [may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737065/server-alias-in-iis)

Comment: thanks@RiggsFolly , If I understaood correctly then alias or Virtual directory , you access than I can access via http/https ?

Comment: I think so, but I am not an IIS expert

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Answer (score 0):

PHP-cgi in IIS execute files under application pool identity not IUSR. So please try to replace the application pool identity  with a domain account that have permission to access the files.